# Separating an Array into a comma separated string with quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm manually building an SQL query where I'm using an Array in the params hash for an SQL IN statement, like: ("WHERE my_field IN('blue','green','red')").   So I need to take the contents of the array and output them into a string where each element is single quoted and comma separated (and with no ending comma).

So if the array was: `my_array = ['blue','green','red']`

I'd need a string that looked like: `"'blue','green','red'"`

I'm pretty new to Ruby/Rails but came up with something that worked:

```
if !params[:colors].nil?
   @categories_array = params[:colors][:categories]
   @categories_string =""
   for x in @categories_array
      @categories_string += "'" + x + "',"
   end
   @categories_string.chop!     #remove the last comma
end
```

So, I'm good but curious as to what a proper and more consise way of doing this would look like?

Comment: @user548744 Don't forget to mark the correct answers as accepted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality is built into ActiveRecord:

```
Model.where(:my_field => ['blue','green','red'])
```

Answer (score 13):

Use `map` and `join`:

```
@categories_string = @categories_array.map {|element|
  "'#{element}'"
}.join(',')
```

Comment: If i want this array in this form then what should be the code.
blue(line break)
green(linebreak)
red

Answer (score 5):

Are you going to pass this string on to a ActiveRecord find method?

If so, ActiveRecord will handle this for you automatically:

```
categories_array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
Model.find(:all, :conditions => ["category in (?)", categories_array])

# => SELECT * FROM models WHERE (category in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated. In this case I have a search form and (because I don't have the ability to get Sphinx installed on our internal work server) I'm using a MySQL full text search. I haven't seen a way to use an ActiveRecord find method when you need to use a MySQL 'WHERE MATCH', so I've assuming I have to go with building a query string manually and using a 'find_by_sql' method. This is all still really new to me though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the parameter hash you don't have to do any thing special:

```
Model.all(:conditions => {:category => @categories_array})
# => SELECT * FROM models WHERE (category in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails (actually ActiveSupport, part of the Rails framework) offers a very nice [Array#to_sentence method](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence).

If you are using Rails or ActiveSupport, you can call

```rb
['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'monkey'].to_sentence # "dog, cat, bird, and monkey"
```

Comment: This does not add quotes